# Kotlin putExtra is not being resolved

Tags: kotlin

I am facing the issue with `putExtra` resolved which is not being recognized. I have clue what could be missing as I thought maybe there should be `intent.putExtra(CONTACT_ID, contact)` but it does not solve anything.

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val contact: Contact by lazy {
    intent?.getSerializableExtra(CONTACT_ID) as Contact
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent{
        MyTheme{
            ProfileScreen(contact)
        }
    }
}

companion object{
    private const val CONTACT_ID = "contact_id"
    fun newIntent(context: Context, contact: Contact) =
        Intent(context, ProfileActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(CONTACT_ID, contact)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Contact` conform to `Serializable`?

Comment: Yes, @RickyMo you were right, thanks!